# Vaadin - remove cell borders in table

Tags: html, css, eclipse, vaadin

I have created a table in Eclipse with the help of Vaadin.

I managed to remove the borders of the table with following line:

```
tblResetButton.addStyleName(Reindeer.TABLE_BORDERLESS) ;
```

but this still leaves me with a vertical line like this:

[image: example]

Is there a way to hide all the cell borders? And an extra bonus, would it be possible to give the first cell (the one with "Gebruiker") the color `#F4F4F4` and the second cell (the textbox) the color `#E2E2E2`

---

EDIT:

the formlayout would be good, but I can't seem to get the background colors working so I reverted to the tables. This is the code:

**JAVA**

```
tblReset.addContainerProperty("Gebruiker", String.class, null);

tblReset.setCellStyleGenerator(new Table.CellStyleGenerator() {
            @Override
            public String getStyle(Table source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
                if("Gebruiker".equals(propertyId)){
                    return "style-name-with-black-background";
                } else {
                    return "style-name-with-yellow-background" ;
                }
            }
        });
```

**CSS**

```
.style-name-with-black-background {
    background-color: black ;
}

.style-name-with-yellow-background {
    background-color: yellow ;
}
```

Comment: just to have it asked: you don't plan to abuse a table to be a FormLayout?

Comment: First time Vaadin user so I'm going to check it out

Comment: What was the issue with the form layout? Did you check the [book section for the form styles](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.formlayout.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the answer to cfrick's comment is no, looks like it depends on what theme you're using:

- If it's [valo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/) ([recommended for a few reasons](https://vaadin.com/valo) and from the screenshot seems like you're already using it but not 100% sure) then there are [2 other styles, `ValoTheme.TABLE_NO_VERTICAL_LINES` & `ValoTheme.TABLE_NO_HORIZONTAL_LINES`](http://vaadin.com/download/release/7.4/7.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/themes/ValoTheme.html#TABLE_NO_HORIZONTAL_LINES).
- In reindeer they seem to be missing so you'll probably have to manually define custom style(s) in [your theme](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html). See below a simple/naive attempt:

*add the style to the table*

```
table.setStyleName("no-vertical-lines-or-border");
```

*while defining it in your theme*

```
  .v-table-no-vertical-lines-or-border .v-table-header-wrap /* remove header-table borders */,
  .v-table-no-vertical-lines-or-border .v-table-body /* remove body-table borders */,
  .v-table-no-vertical-lines-or-border .v-table-cell-content /* remove cell borders */ {
    border: none;
  }
```

As for the cells, you can use a [style generator](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.css), again with your custom defined styles for each cell, something along the lines of:

```
    table.setCellStyleGenerator(new Table.CellStyleGenerator() {
        @Override
        public String getStyle(Table source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
            if("description".equals(propertyId)){
                return "style-name-with-F4F4F4-background";
            } else {
                return "style-name-with-E2E2E2-background";
            }
        }
    });
```

**P.S.:** Given that you're experimenting, and if you're working with Vaadin versions 7.2+, take a look at the [support for font icons](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+font+icons) which may come in very handy at times, for example the embedded [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/):

[image: FontAwesome basic usage]

Comment: The theme is Reindeer. I updated the question, could you take a look at it?

Comment: @TimothyPersoon Like I said, you'll have to manually define a class for your table in which to remove he borders, please see update answer.

Comment: @TimothyPersoon I'm glad, but perhaps we could do even better if you tell us what issues you had with the FormLayout.

Comment: Something simple, I couldn't get the background color the way I wanted it